# Angular router.navigate() is not working after being redirected using AuthGaurd

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm implementing routing in my Angular application with route guard

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

auth.gaurd.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

login.component.ts (funtion that responds once click on login button)

```
public onSubmit(loginForm): void {
    this.loginFailed = false;
    this.submitted = true;

    if (loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.authService.login(this.userName, this.password)) {
      console.log('ABLE TO CONSOLE THIS'); // THIS LINE IS EXECUTING 
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } else {
      this.loginFailed = true;
    }
  }
```

At first, if I'm not authenticated and I try to navigate directly to `/dashboard`, I'm being navigated back to `'/'` route which is right behavior. But, when I try to login again (without refreshing page) with correct credentials I'm not able to login and cannot navigate to `/dashboard` anymore.

Could anyone please let me know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you get any errors? I also recommend to remove a slash `/` from `...navigate(['dashboard])`.

Comment: @DmitryS. I tried but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using, canActivate, which only prevents the unauthorized access of your route but does not prevent to load the module. so your module is already being loaded thats why its not working withought , refresh .

I will suggest you to use canLoad with canActive

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and suggested way to handle a guard redirect since Angular v7 would be to return a URLTree inside your guard, instead of imperatively navigating and returning false afterwards. This helps to prevent other navigation related bugs.

Your code might look something like this afterwards:

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return this.router.parseUrl('/');
        }
    }
```

You could read more about that here: https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/